# Smooth transition of player from left to right on tap in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

```
void Update () {
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2 && transform.position.x > -6.25f) transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x - 4.50f, transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2 && transform.position.x < 4.50f) transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 4.50f, transform.position.y,transform.position.z);
}}
```

The above code helps the player to move left and right on tapping left and right within the screen. I want to attain similar control but in a smoother transition from left to right and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Codes like this should help you, but you may need to go over the official tutorials.

```cs
public float xLimitMin, xLimitMax, speed;

private void Update () 
{
  if (Input.touchCount > 0)
  {
    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if (touch.position.x < Screen.width / 2 && transform.position.x > xLimitMin) transform.Translate(-speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    if (touch.position.x > Screen.width / 2 && transform.position.x < xLimitMax) transform.Translate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This definitely is not the best way to go, but it works. (e.g. not handling multi-touch, frequent access to Time.deltaTime, the code should more general, ...etc)

Comment: And if, you are trying to find a solution where the player smoothly moves towards the points with certain gaps (like a grid movement), I will edit my code